# Angular app not going full screen

Tags: html, css, angular

For some reason, the home page of Angular app-to-be is not displaying full screen.

Home component looks like this:

*home.component.html*

```
<div id="homeScreen">
  <banner></banner>
  <div [ngStyle]="{ 'margin-left' : (banner.menuVisible) ? '150px'  : '0'}">
     Home component works!
  </div>

</div>
```

*home.component.css*

```
#homeScreen {
    /* background-image: url(http://ikteocheckpoint.gr/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/KTEO-CHECKPOINT-BACKGROUND.jpg); */
    background-image:  url(../../../assets/BackgroundImage.jpg);
}
```

*home.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BannerComponent } from '../dashboard/banner/banner.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(BannerComponent) banner : BannerComponent;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Banner component looks like this:

*banner.component.html*

```
<nav>
    <button id="menuButton" (click)="toggleMenuVisible()">
        <div id="menuBars">
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <a id="pageTitle" routerLink="/home">Open Source Roads</a>
</nav>
<menu *ngIf="menuVisible"></menu>
```

*banner.component.css*

```
nav { 
    text-align: center;
    overflow : hidden;
  }

menu { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: left;
    z-index : 1;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    position: fixed;
}

#menuButton { 
    background-color : black;
    border : 2px solid yellow;
    height : 30px;
    width : 30px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding: 5px 3px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    float : left;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

#pageTitle { 
    color: white;
    text-decoration: initial;
}

#menuBars { 
    float : right;
}

#menuButton:hover { 
    background-color : white;
}

#menuButton:hover .bar { 
    background-color : black;
}

#menuButton:active { 
    background-color: yellow;
}

#menuButton:active .bar {
    background-color : black;
}

.bar { 
    background-color : white;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
}

.bar + .bar { 
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#pageTitle {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

*banner.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'banner',
  templateUrl: './banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banner.component.css']
})
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {

  public menuVisible = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public toggleMenuVisible() { 
    this.menuVisible = !this.menuVisible;
  }

}
```

Menu component looks like this:

*menu.component.html*

```
<nav>
  <div>
    <ul class="menu" class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a class="menu-option" routerLink="home">Home</a></li>
      <!-- other menu options here -->
      <li><a class="menu-option" routerLink="about">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="menu-option" routerLink="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

*menu.component.css*

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

li {
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

.menu-option { 
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.menu-option:hover { 
    color: yellow;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**The Big Picture**

The above code produces the following screen:

[image]

Forgive my rustiness with front-end UI development, but how to make this 100% height?

**UPDATE**: I just remembered that I could do

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
```

on the main Component (`HomeComponent`) to force it to be full-screen, but that would mean that I'd have to do it on every Component. Also, doing this on the `AppComponent`, applying to its children like:

```
#page-content > *:not(:first-child) { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

will not work either, nor will `#page-content > *` selector, because `HomeComponent` is injected via `router-outlet`.

Comment: Hi Mike, it looks like you skinned the nav bar. The nav bar is not very tall, and a div by default will only grow as tall as the content. Basically you need to specify a height for the div, or use a min-height. If your intent was to have the graphic cover the screen, use body background image instead, or make additional divs below the nav bar that have a height.

Comment: Even if I give the `<menu>` `height: 100%`, it still isn't working (but menu is full height). I'll post updated code

Comment: /* Menu goes full height, but not the `HomeComponent` it is part of */

Comment: Can you put up an example on stackblitz?

Comment: @yurzui Here it is, but for some reason, there's error on this site (on valid code from my machine): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ogoj2d

Comment: Option 1 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hw8ivu?file=src%2Fstyles.css

Comment: Option 2 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-91yv8e?file=src/styles.css